# Writing to MongoDB with PHP issue

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a Sigfox callback that sends data to a PHP file (recordSigfox.php) that writes it to MongoDB. The below code worked (only read 'data'), but now I also want to send time and it will not work. Can anyone help me find the issue? When I test in the browser with the callback variables it says error 500.

Callback from sigfox: 
GET http://server..../recordSigfox.php?id=4D4000&time=1551849760&data=007f5542264ad3c0&ack=true HTTP/1.0

```
  <html>
  <head>
   <title>Unpack</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php
    $user = "muntean";
    require '/var/composer/vendor/autoload.php';
    $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    echo "Connection to database successfully. ";
    $collection = new MongoDB\Collection($manager, $user, 'testData');
    echo "Connection to collection successful. ";

    //get data from the address bar/sigfox message
    //http://sbsrv1.cs.nuim.ie/fyp/muntean/list.php
    $_data = $_GET["data"];
    $coord = unpack('flat/flon', pack('H*', $_data));
    $lt = $coord['lat'];
    $lg = $coord['lon'];

    $document = array(
      'Latitude' => $lt,
      'Longitude' => $lg
    );

    try {
      $collection->insertOne($document);
   } catch (\Exception $e) {
      print("Insert failed.");
      print_r($document);
      print_r($e);
      exit();
   }

    $filter = [];
    $options = [];
    $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
    $cursor = $manager->executeQuery("$user.testData", $query);
    print("The contents of the collection $user.testData are:");
    print_r($cursor->toArray());
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

New code that isn't working, just added a line to get and write time:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Unpack</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php
    $user = "muntean";
    require '/var/composer/vendor/autoload.php';
    $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    echo "Connection to database successfully. ";
    $collection = new MongoDB\Collection($manager, $user, 'testData');
    echo "Connection to collection successful. ";

    //get data from the address bar/sigfox message
    //http://sbsrv1.cs.nuim.ie/fyp/muntean/list.php
    $_data = $_GET["data"];
    $_time = $_GET["time];
    $coord = unpack('flat/flon', pack('H*', $_data));
    $lt = $coord['lat'];
    $lg = $coord['lon'];

    $document = array(
      'Latitude' => $lt,
      'Longitude' => $lg
      'Time' => $_time
    );

    try {
      $collection->insertOne($document);
   } catch (\Exception $e) {
      print("Insert failed.");
      print_r($document);
      print_r($e);
      exit();
   }

    $filter = [];
    $options = [];
    $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
    $cursor = $manager->executeQuery("$user.testData", $query);
    print("The contents of the collection $user.testData are:");
    print_r($cursor->toArray());
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<AudibleGroan>` You are using the wrong PHP library. `MongoDB\Driver` is from the `pecl` installation and is a low level interface for "driver and ODM authors". You need to install the composer package [PHPLib](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/) and use that. Read the documentation page and look at the [pretty picture jeremy drew](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.overview.php) since the common response is when you see that picture you are meant to understand why this installation done in various parts `</AudibleGroan>`

Comment: Hi the server is university-provided. That is the driver installed/I was told to use. The first code example works fully for recording to mongo, is getting this higher-level driver installed strictly necessary?

Comment: You have my permission to show my comment there to your lecturer, as they are telling you to use the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a missing " at the end of Time and a  missing comma in the document